# If $H$ is a proper subgroup of a $p$-group $G$, then $H$ is proper in $N_G(H)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $H$ be a proper subgroup of $p$-group $G$. Show that the normalizer of $H$ in $G$, denoted $N_G(H)$, is strictly larger than $H$, and that $H$ is contained in a normal subgroup of index $p$.

Here's what I've got so far:

- If $H$ is normal, $N_G(H)$ is all of $G$ and we are done.
- If $H$ is not normal, then suppose for the sake of contradiction that $N_G(H)=H$. Then there is no element outside of $H$ that fixes $H$ by conjugation. But the center $Z(G)$ of $G$ does fix $H$, so $Z(G)$ must be a subgroup of $H$.

Don't know if I'm going on the right path or not, but either way can't really think my way out of this one... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why the finite-group tag has been added to the OP?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are on the right track. Now look at the subgroup $H/Z$ of $G/Z$. By induction, its normalizer is strictly larger than $H/Z$. Say it contains the residue class $\overline x$ of $x \in G$ where $\overline x \not\in H/Z$. Now show that $x$ also normalizes $H$ in $G$ to get a contradiction.

Comment: Could you clarify:
1) By induction from what? I thought we were assuming that N(H) is not larger than H.
2) By residue class do you just mean the elements outside of H/Z?

Comment: 1) The induction is on the order of $G$. Since $G$ is a $p$-group its center $Z$ is non-trivial, so $G/Z$ is strictly smaller than $G$. 2) By the residue class of $x$ I mean its image in the quotient group $G/Z$, so the coset $xZ$ if you like.

Comment: Very clear. I will look into this, thank you sir.

Comment: What about the second part, with H being contained in a normal subgroup index p? Any hints there?

Comment: @BenjaminLu You know that taking normalizers strictly enlarges the subgroup. Suppose you repeat this a lot of times. What would happen?

Comment: Right, but what if during this process we hit a normal group that is smaller than the maximal group?

Comment: @BenjaminLu You pick a larger subgroup and continue. On reflection I suppose this isn't any simpler than immediately passing to a maximal subgroup.

Comment: @marlu isn't p-group having non-trivial centre a corollary of the class equation? Can I know how exactly is the induction done?

Comment: Where did you find this problem?

Comment: I'm having trouble showing $x$ normailzes $H$. Any tips?

Comment: @FerrisBoyler I have written out a complete answer, which you may refer to for your question (if you are still interested).

Answer (score 0):

Let me write a complete answer with the hint proposed by @marlu .

---

Let $G$ be a $p$-group. So, $|G|=p^r$ for some $r\ge 1$.

Let us look the base case that $|G|=p$. If $H<G$, then $H=\{e\}<G=N_G (\{e\})$.

Assume that, for all $s<r$, if $|G|=p^s$ and $H<G$, then we $H< N_G (H)$.

Let us now consider the case that $|G|=p^r$. Note that $H\leq N_G(H)$. If $H<N_G(H)$, then we are done. So we may assume that $H=N_G(H)$, which forces that $Z\unlhd H$, where $Z:=Z(G)$.

By our inductive assumption and the fact that $|G/Z|=p^t$ with $t<r$ (where we have used the fact that every finite $p$-group has a non-trivial center), we know the normalizer (group) of $H/Z$ properly contains $H/Z$. Therefore, there exists $\bar{x} \in G/Z$ such that $\bar{x} \notin H/Z$ and $\bar{x}$ normalizes $H/Z$, i.e. $\bar{x} (H/Z)\bar{x}^{-1}=H/Z$.

Let $h\in H$. We then have $\bar{x} (hZ)\bar{x}^{-1}=\tilde{h}Z$ for some $\tilde{h}\in H$. Therefore, $ (xhx^{-1})Z=\tilde{h}Z$, where we have used the fact that $\bar{x}^{-1}=\overline{x^{-1}}$. So, there exist $z,\tilde{z}\in Z$ such that $x hx^{-1}z=\tilde{h}\tilde{z}$, which implies that $xhx^{-1}=\tilde{h}\tilde{z}z^{-1}$. Recall that $Z\leq H$, which implies $\tilde{h}\tilde{z}z^{-1}\in H$ and so $x$ does normalize $H$. Since $\bar{x}\notin H/Z$, it is clear that $x\notin H$, which contradicts with $H=N_G(H)$, which implies that we can only have the case that $H<N_G(H)$.

$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

Comment: My proof may seem a bit tedious because I have almost written out all details. I do so because I want my answer to be as friendly as possible to the beginners, and most importantly, I was a beginner as well.

Comment: Thanks! But can I ask your proof of the second part? That H
 is contained in a normal subgroup of index p
.