# Prove: proper subgroup of p-group is contained in a normal subgroup index p.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Normalizer of subgroup of p-group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234426/normalizer-of-subgroup-of-p-group)

Here's the whole question:

H is a proper subgroup of p-group G. Show that normalizer of H, N(H) is strictly larger than H, and that H is contained in a normal subgroup index p.

With some help I already managed to prove that N(H) is strictly larger than H. But I'm having some trouble with the later half.

I'm thinking we could do something with the quotient group G/N(H) and its order, but then it wouldn't cover the case where H is normal and N(H) is all of G.

Any help appreciated.