# Let H be a proper subgroup of G of order prime $p^k$ and $N(H) = \{a \in G|aHa^{-1} = H\}.$Show that $N(H) \neq H.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be a group of order $p^k$ where p is a prime and k is a positive integer. Let H be a proper subgroup of G and 
$$N(H) = \{a \in G|aHa^{-1} = H\}.$$
Show that 
$$N(H) \neq H.$$

I think I need to show that if $N(H) = H$, then $|H|$ will not divide $p^k$, but I have no idea how to show this.

Elementary answer that does not touch on group action or orbit is preferred.

Comment: possible duplicate of [If $H$ is a proper subgroup of a $p$-group $G$, then $H$ is proper in $N_G(H)$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234426/if-h-is-a-proper-subgroup-of-a-p-group-g-then-h-is-proper-in-n-gh)

Comment: @Leppala do you know how is the induction exactly done in that post? I don't quite understand

Answer (score 7):

Define an action of $\;H\;$ on $\;X:=H/G:=$ the set of left cosets of $\;H\;$ in $\;G\;$ by left shift:

$$h\cdot xH\mapsto (hx)H$$

Notice that the orbit of $\;1H=H\;$ is fixed by $\;H\;\implies\;|\mathcal O(H)|=1\;$, and since the sum of the sizes of the orbits is $\;|X|\;$ and this number is a power of $\;p\;$ , there **must be** another orbit which isn't divided by $\;p\;$,  and the only option left is that its size is $\;1\;$ , again.

Thus, there exists $\;gH\in X\;,\;\;gH\neq H\iff g\notin H\;$ , such that

$$\forall\,h\in H\;,\;\;hgH=gH\implies H^g:=g^{-1}hgH\le H$$

and since $\;|H^g|=|H|<\infty\;$ , we get equality

$$H^g=H\implies g\in N_G(H)\setminus H\;$$

and we're done since clearly $\;H\le N_G(H)\;$ .

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you do the induction:

Assume that $G$ is the **smallest** finite $p$-group such that $\exists H < G$ s.t. $N_G(H) = H$ (that is, $G$ is a minimal counterexample).

Now $Z(G) > 1$ as $G$ is a $p$-group. Naturally $H^z = H \ \forall z \in Z(G)$, hence $Z(G) \leq N_G(H) = H$. Now consider the groups $H/Z(G) < G/Z(G)$. As $Z(G)$ is nontrivial, we have $|G/Z(G)| < |G|$, and thus **by induction** $N_{G/Z(G)}(H/Z(G)) > H/Z(G)$.

Then prove that if $xZ(G) \in N_{G/Z(G)}(H/Z(G)) \ \setminus \ H/Z(G)$, then $x \in N_G(H) \setminus H$ normalizes $H$. This is a **contradiction** as $N_G(H) = H$. Thus the assumption must be false, hence no such counterexample exists.